# Quartz.net for newbies

Tags: .net, asp.net, quartz.net

What is quartz.net how to start using it?

Answer (score 10):

Suggest you start with the tutorial for Quartz.Net at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the examples in the folder src \ Quartz.Examples.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first think of a few points, if will want to use the Quartz in memory or stored in a database,it will start a server, etc.
After that u must create a class to manage your Schedule and another containing the Job you want to run, what I'm saying is a simple example. I will demonstrate how to do this in the following scenario:
Sqlite to store data, a Job class with log and everything else with Log. And will be run every day at 10:30 AM.

your web.config

```
<add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="ServerScheduler" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
<add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />

<add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />

<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString" value="Data Source=yourdb.db;Version=3;Foreign Keys=ON;" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.clustered" value="false" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.StdAdoDelegate, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.dataSource.default.provider" value="SQLite-1094" />
<add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz" />
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.port" value="555" />
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
<add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType" value="tcp" />
```

Create a class called Schedule.cs:

```
public static class Schedule
{

    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Schedule));

    public static ITrigger BuildTrigger(int hour, int minute)
    {


        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                    .StartNow()
                                     .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(hour,minute))
                                    .Build();
        return trigger;
    }




    public static IScheduler InicializarScheduler()
    {


        var scheduleMigracao = Schedule.GetScheduler();

        if (!scheduleMigracao.IsStarted)
            scheduleMigracao.Start();

        logger.Info("Scheduler started successfully");

        return scheduleMigracao;
    }

    public static IJobDetail BuildJogDetail<T>(string WorkFlowId, string Group) where T : IJob
    {
        return JobBuilder.Create<T>()
               .WithIdentity(WorkFlowId, Group)
               .RequestRecovery()
               .Build();
    }

    private static IScheduler GetScheduler()
    {
        try
        {

            IScheduler scheduler = SchedulerRepository.Instance.Lookup("DefaultQuartzScheduler");
            if (scheduler == null)
            {
                var factoryScheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory();

                return factoryScheduler.GetScheduler();
            }
            else
            {
                return scheduler;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Server initialization failed:" + ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Create a class called TestJob.cs

```
public class TestJob : IInterruptableJob
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TestJob));

    public void Interrupt()
    {

    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {

            Log.DebugFormat("{0}****{0}Job {1} Start @ {2} next scheduled for {3}{0}***{0}",
                                                                    Environment.NewLine,
                                                                    context.JobDetail.Key,
                                                                    context.FireTimeUtc.Value.ToString("r"),
                                                                    context.NextFireTimeUtc.Value.ToString("r"));


           //implement your logic


            Log.DebugFormat("{0}****{0}Job {1} executed with sucess at  @ {2}",
                                                                    Environment.NewLine,
                                                                    context.JobDetail.Key,
                                                                    context.FireTimeUtc.Value.ToString("r"));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Log.DebugFormat("{0}***{0}Failed: {1}{0}***{0}", Environment.NewLine, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

in your Global.asax place:

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static void BuildingQuartzMetadataSqLite1090()
    {
        var metaData = new DbMetadata();
        metaData.AssemblyName = "System.Data.SQLite, Version = 1.0.94.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139";
        metaData.BindByName = true;
        metaData.CommandBuilderType = typeof(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommandBuilder);
        metaData.CommandType = typeof(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand);
        metaData.ConnectionType = typeof(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection);
        metaData.ExceptionType = typeof(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException);
        metaData.ParameterDbType = typeof(System.Data.SQLite.TypeAffinity);
        metaData.ParameterDbTypePropertyName = "DbType";
        metaData.ParameterNamePrefix = "@";
        metaData.ParameterType = typeof(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteParameter);
        metaData.UseParameterNamePrefixInParameterCollection = true;

        DbProvider.RegisterDbMetadata("SQLite-1094",metaData);
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          BuildingQuartzMetadataSqLite1090();
           Schedule.InicializarScheduler();
           Schedule.ScheduleJob(Schedule.BuildJogDetail<TestJob>("TestJob","GrupoTest"), Schedule.BuildTrigger(10, 30));
    }
}
```

Any questions just ask